# Receiving arrays in asp.net core web api form axios.post

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-core, axios

For example I have this code, that sends data to the asp.net core 6 web api controller.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Id", 1);
formData.append("PhotoNames", ["name1", "name2", "name3"]);
formData.append("Photos", [file1, file2, file3)];
axios.post("/api/MyController", formData);
```

`file1, file2, file3` are the photos, which I received form `<input type="file"/>`.

I handled the same request, but without arrays, by using this code in `MyController.cs`:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PhotoName{ get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] ImageModel file)
{
   //Using all the data from the request here   
}
```

The request looked like:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Id", 1);
formData.append("PhotoName", "name1");
formData.append("Photo", file1);
axios.post("/api/MyController", formData);
```

How can I handle post request with arrays in it? What kind of class and function I need to use in `MyController.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before coding, you need know the following knowledge:

- The formData key name should match the model property name.
- The model property should be a List or an Array.
- `formData.append("PhotoNames", ["name1", "name2", "name3"]);` post one item to the List by FormData instead of list item. You need post like below:

  ```
   formData.append("PhotoName", "name1");
   formData.append("PhotoName", "name2");
   formData.append("PhotoName", "name3");
  ```

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[] PhotoName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile[] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="FileList" />
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input[name='FileList']").change(function () {
       const formData = new FormData();

        $("input[name='FileList']").each(function () {
            var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
            if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                $.each(ReadyToUpload, function (i, file) {
                    formData.append("Photo", file);
                });
            }
        });
        formData.append("Id", 1);
        formData.append("PhotoName", "name1");
        formData.append("PhotoName", "name2");
        formData.append("PhotoName", "name3");
        //formData.append("Photos", [file1, file2, file3)];
        axios.post("https://localhost:44397/api/WeatherForecast", formData);
      
    })        
    </script>
}
```

Api:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromForm] ImageModel file)
    {
        //Using all the data from the request here   
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try making PhotoNames nad Photos form data an array

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Id", 1);
formData.append("PhotoNames[]", ["name1", "name2", "name3"]);
formData.append("Photos[]", [file1, file2, file3)];
axios.post("/api/MyController", formData);
```

Comment: @Killsan yes.  ...